# How to create a variable from specific part of command output in powershell script

Tags: powershell

PowerShell script runs a command to give me total bytes and total free bytes of my harddisk. I want to pick those two returned values as variables to do some calculations with but I'm not sure how to set a variable to a specific part of a command's output.

After looking through similar questions I cant apply the same logic to my situations. I have never used PowerShell before and not very familiar with Windows servers. Any recommended tutorials would be welcomed.

```
fsutil volume diskfree C:
```

> Total # of free bytes : 1234567
>
> Total # of bytes: 7654321

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would instead use PowerShell's `Get-WmiObject` command and look at the `Win32_LogicalDisk` class. You could do something like this:

```
$cDrive = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_LogicalDisk -Filter "DeviceId='C:'"
```

That way you can get the free space and size attributes of the drive and manipulate them however you like. For example, this would show you the free space on the C drive in GB:

```
[Math]::Round( $cDrive.FreeSpace / 1GB)
```

Comment: Would i be able to use this output to get the percentage of free space? (Freespace/Size)*100 = percent

Comment: @a.smith Yes [grin]. `$percentFree = ( $cDrive.FreeSpace / $cDrive.Size) * 100`

Answer (score 3):

You can use WMI from Powershell.

```
$diskData = Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk -Filter "DeviceID='C:'" | Select-Object Size, FreeSpace

Write-Host $diskData.Size
Write-Host $diskData.FreeSpace
```

Comment: This helped me a lot. The ability to separate the integer value from the variable name!

Answer (score 2):

Get-WmiObject as mentioned in the other answers *is* the way to go but for the fun of it

```
$freespace, $size = [int64[]]((fsutil volume diskfree C:)[0,1] -split ': ')[1,3]
Write-Output $freespace, $size
```

<sub>Disclaimer: note that this breaks when microsoft decides to change the output format of fsutil</sub>

Comment: Thanks, useful to know how to pick values from a command but yes i will go with Get-WmiObject as above